# JasperReports one to many relationship

Tags: jasper-reports

I have two datasets:

*Job*  and *Products*.

Its a one to many relationship.

I can do an *inner join* just fine and get the data just fine, but when I try to display report with *JasperReports*, for every line it spits out, it repeats the *Job* data.

Where I just want it to display the *Job* data once per line and then show the 3-5 *Products* associated with that *Job*.

Instead of showing 5 lines each repeating the *Job* info.

Anybody come across this problem?

Do I have to embed a sub-report or something like that?

Otherwise, I can just do this all manually, which is fine, but I figured I'd give *JasperReports* a shot.

Comment: Show your tables, it is hard to understand the problem.

Comment: You can use subreport or you can use groups

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want repeated values for any text filed such as "job" in your report,Go to Ireport and select "Job" text filed and go to the property section and unchecked the "Print Repeated Values" property.
and if you want to change in xml:-

```
  <textField>
<reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="148" y="48" width="652" height="20"/>
<textElement>
    <font size="12"/>
  </textElement>
```